# A 2D static problem with known analytical solution

Tags: finite-element

I am looking for a 2D static problem (i.e. planar stress/strain) with known analytical solution.

The purpose for that is to verify my self-written code in matlab for solving 2D static problems.

Any references would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Use the method of manufactured solutions. Here is a [link to a Sandia technical report](http://prod.sandia.gov/techlib/access-control.cgi/2000/001444.pdf) describing the method. It will give you considerably more flexibility in testing your code for the order-of-accuracy of your numerical methods.